# Mainframe COBOL COMPUTE TRUNC Query

Tags: cobol, mainframe, zos

I wonder why there is different in the result for those two cases.

Working Storage:

```
WS-SUM-LEN PIC S9(4) COMP. 
WS-LEN-9000   PIC 9(5) VALUE 9000.
WS-TMP-LEN    PIC 9(5).
WS-FIELD-A    PIC X(2000).
```

Case 1) `COMPUTE WS-SUM-LEN = WS-LEN-9000 + LENGTH OF WS-FIELD-A`

Result: WS-SUM-LEN = 1000

Case 2)

```
MOVE LENGTH OF WS-FIELD-A TO WS-TMP-LEN
COMPUTE WS-SUM-LEN = WS-LEN-9000 + WS-TMP-LEN
```

Result: WS-SUM-LEN = 11000

The compiler option is TRUNC(OPT). Why there is no trunc occur for case 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Binary fields in IBM's Enterprise COBOL**

***Warnings***

Compiler option TRUNC determines how code for binary fields is generated.

**Do not just up and change from your site's default setting of option TRUNC**. The different settings for TRUNC can give different results.

Changing from TRUNC(BIN) to TRUNC(STD) will give different results for any values beyond the decimal-values represented by the PICture defining the field. For a signed field, the same applies for the negative value.

```
01  a-good-name              BINARY PIC 99.

    ADD 1                    TO a-good-name
```

With TRUNC(STD) the result will be truncated once 99 is reached. With TRUNC(BIN) the result will be truncated once 65535 is reached (if the field were signed, the truncation would be at 99 as before for TRUNC(STD) and 32767 for TRUNC(BIN)).

Changing from TRUNC(BIN) to TRUNC(OPT), without program changes, is only possible if all, entirely all, usage of binary fields is limited to decimal-values represented by the PICture. Particular pieces of code may appear to "work", but it would be a massive coincidence if all use of binary fields gave the same result between the two compiler options, on your system.

It is similar for changing from TRUNC(STD) to TRUNC(OPT). Although the amount of coincidence for working would be smaller, this would increase a false sense of security leaving the potential for subtle differences to be missed for some time.

Changing from genuine use of TRUNC(OPT) to either TRUNC(STD) or TRUNC(BIN) is possible without effort. However, why would you want to?

However, if your use is not genuine (using TRUNC(OPT) with data that does not conform to PICture), then your original results are unreliable, and you *will get differences* if changing to TRUNC(STD) and likely get difference changing to TRUNC(BIN).

In short, changing the site-default for compiler option TRUNC is something to be considered very carefully, and must include provision for verification of results.

Sites *do* at times make such a change, the only ones I know of are TRUNC(BIN) (mostly) and TRUNC(STD) to TRUNC(OPT), for performance reasons. These have been done as projects, not just by changing the option and blundering on from there.

**Do not override the site-default for TRUNC within systems**. If you have programs which are using the same binary data (from files, databases, inter-program communication, messages, or any other way) and they don't all treat the data in the same way, it is asking for trouble.

*Some myths*

Further explanation will be given later in the text.

> 1. There is a difference between TRUNC(BIN) and making all your binary
>      fields COMP-5 (or COMPUTATIONAL-5).

There is no difference whatsoever. When TRUNC(BIN) is specified, the compiler simply treats all binary fields as COMP-5.

> 2. Native-binary is faster than COBOL binary (a binary field with decimal limits defined by the PICture clause).

Although the term itself makes many experienced people think it will be faster ("it'll be like when I code it myself in Assembler") it is in fact slower, on the whole. The slowing-down increases as the field-size increases.

> 3. Native-binary (COMP-5/COMPUTATIONAL-5) does not truncate.

It does. It truncates to field-size. Because it truncates to field-size, the intermediate fields must always be larger than the source fields, which means more instructions must be used, and different instructions.

Also, and important to know, the ON SIZE ERROR clause (which can be used with all arithmetic verbs) *always only uses the PICture clause to determine that a size-error has occurred*. That is, if you have a COMP-5 PIC S9(4), which can contain a maximum positive value of 32,767 and do this:

```
MULTIPLY that-field BY 10 GIVING that-field
  ON SIZE ERROR
      DISPLAY "Busted"
END-MULTIPLY
```

Any value above 9999 will cause the DISPLAY to be processed.

Which really means "don't use ON SIZE ERROR with COMP-5 or TRUNC(BIN)".

> 4. TRUNC(OPT) generates optimal code.

In isolation, it does. However this does not preclude further optimisations from compiler option OPTIMIZE/OPT across a wider context.

> 5. When using binary fields, always use the maximum PICture for the size of the field

A binary field with 1-4 digits will occupy a half-word, two bytes of storage. With 5-9 digits, a word, or a fullword, of four bytes. With 10-18 digits, a double-word of eight bytes.

The aged recommendation is to always specify four digits, nine digits and 18 digits (well, no-one really goes above nine, do they...?).

This is advice I've received in the past, and given out myself. However, in Enterprise COBOL it is not good advice.

The best advice here is to define the number of digits needed. This will at times improve performance, will never degrade performance, and will make the program easier to understand by best describing the data.

> 6. When using binary fields, always make them signed.

More advice I've received and given in the past. Untrue with Enterprise COBOL. If a field can contain a negative value, make it signed. Otherwise make it unsigned.

At times, with interfaces, it is not explicit whether a field should be signed. However, it will be explicit from the maximum value expected. As will the field definition (the USAGE).

For instance, an SQL VARCHAR as a host-variable can have a maximum size of 32767 bytes. Since the actual length is held in a two-byte binary field, the field should be signed. Any value "above" 32767 will be misinterpreted by DB2/SQL.

> 7. Since nine decimal digits can fully fit within a word/fullword, there is no problem using nine decimal digits for a COMP/COMP-4/BINARY definition (without TRUNC(BIN)).

Since the compiler has to take care of decimal truncation, and since anything which could lead to truncation would require the "next size up", a binary field of nine digits can require a double-word intermediate field. So requires code to convert to a double-word, and convert the result back from a double-word to a word. If nine digits are required, it will generally be better to define 10 digits and save on the conversions.

**Note**

The above is all known to hold true for Enterprise COBOL up to V4.2.

IBM has entirely rewritten the code-generation and optimisation (now at two possible levels of optimisation) For Enterprise COBOL V5. There is considerable improvement in the treatment of binary fields, including, for instance, only doing the truncation of values once it is known that truncation is necessary. I am not aware that the use of V5 changes anything here other than the scale of performance differences. All general usage of binary fields should be faster with V5 than with earlier versions of Enterprise COBOL.

**Binary fields**

COBOL, for binary fields, uses decimal maxima determined by the PICture size.

Such a field with PIC 9 can contain a maximum value of 9 before truncation. If signed, the range of values is -9 to +9. Values outside that range will be truncated.

For PIC 99, 99, and if signed -99 to 99.

For PIC 999, 999,and if signed -999 to 999.

You get the pictu... idea.

It is down to the compiler-implementation as to how those values are stored.

Indeed, according to the Standard, COBOL only recently (1985) had support for binary fields (USAGE BINARY). Which and how actual "non-display" fields were supported was down to USAGE COMPUTATIONAL, whose specifics were compiler-dependent.

Generally across compilers COMP, COMP-1 and COMP-2 (binary, with decimal maxima, short floating-point and long floating-point) are standard, though not part of the Standard. Beyond COMP-2, what the field definitions mean can vary amongst compilers.

So, first recommendation, suggest that your local site standards use BINARY instead of COMP for new code (and PACKED-DECIMAL instead of COMP-3, for packed-decimal fields). BINARY (and COMP-4) within Enterprise COBOL is simply an alias of COMP, so there is absolutely no problem in doing this.

There is another type of binary field, which is the native-binary field. In Enterprise COBOL this is USAGE COMP-5.

COMP-5 has its field-size determined by the PICture definition, but its maxima are that of the full bit-pattern possible for the field size. A PIC S9(4) COMP-5 can contain -32768 to 32767.

Note at this point that a native-binary field, and this may seem counter-intuitive, generally needs more generated machine-code to support its use. This is because it truncates to field-size, rather than PICture.

Note also that there is one place where this does not happen, which is ON SIZE ERROR, which will be true if the value exceeds the PICture size. Which means, to my mind, don't use ON SIZE ERROR with COMP-5 (or TRUNC(BIN), see soon) fields.

**Compiler option TRUNC**

The compiler option TRUNC defines how machine-code is generated for binary fields. There are three options:

TRUNC(BIN)

Truncation to field-size.

This treats all the non-native-binary fields in the program (COMP/COMP-4/BINARY) as native-binary (as though they had been defined as COMP-5).

This allows the full range of bit patterns to be used, but has impacts on performance.

TRUNC(STD)

Truncation to PICture size.

Generates machine-code for the COBOL Standard truncation to PICture size. PIC 9(n) can contain no more than n significant digits, they will be truncated when the field is a "target" (field value changes).

TRUNC(OPT)

Truncation of any type only used if it happens to be convenient.

I describe this as being a contract between the coder and the compiler. The coder contracts to never (as in never) allow a value to exceed the PICture size. The compiler contracts to always get it right in such a case.

If the coder breaks the contract the coder is entirely to blame for the ensuing rubbish.

**When to use each setting of TRUNC (further recommendation)**

`BIN` Never. Use COMP-5 for individual fields where they require access to all bits (pay attention to SQL and CICS "system" fields, and external data from non-Mainframe sources, and inter-language communication between COBOL and JAVA/C/C++ and anywhere else where the data-maxima for a field are beyond the PICture and it is not possible to make the field bigger (as the actual logical definition of the field size is outside your program).

`STD` use this unless all, as in all, your data always, as in always, conforms to PICture.

`OPT` use this only, as in only, if all, as in all, your data always, as in always, conforms to PICture.

If you have COMP PIC 99, for instance, you must not, when using OPT, allow that to have a value of 99, and then add one to it. Or anything similar

**The Answer**

You used TRUNC(OPT), entering into the contract. You immediately broke the contract. It is your fault.

**Warning**

If your site is using TRUNC(OPT) and not everyone is fully aware of the implications, you will, as in will, have problems.

**Substantiation of the Myths from above**

> 1. There is a difference between TRUNC(BIN) and making all your binary
>      fields COMP-5 (or COMPUTATIONAL-5).

Define two fields in small program. They should be defined as COMP/COMP-4/BINARY (or COMPUTATIONAL/COMPUTATIONAL-4 if that is your bent).

In the program, add a literal to each of the fields (do this with two separate statements, to make it easier to follow, unless you are experience with the generated code in a listing).

Compile the program with compiler options LIST,NOOFFSET (this will produce, in the compiler listing, output showing the generated machine-code in a so-called "pseudo-assembler" format) and TRUNC(BIN).

Copy the program. In the copy, change the USAGE of the two fields to COMP-5 (or COMPUTATIONAL-5).

Compile this program, again with LIST,NOOFFSET but this time the value for TRUNC is irrelevant as it does not affect COMP-5 fields.

Compare the output listings. If there is one byte difference, eat someone's hat.

> 2. Native-binary is faster than COBOL binary (a binary field with decimal limits defined by the PICture clause).

From this discussion at IBM's COBOL Cafe: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=ae9ef6bc-6e4e-43f8-a814-e66bea25fb8c&ps=25

Here's a multiply of a PIC 9(3) by a PIC 9(5).

With TRUNC(STD)

```
000023  MULTIPLY                                                             
   000258  5820 8008               L     2,8(0,8)                PIC9-5      
   00025C  4C20 8000               MH    2,0(0,8)                PIC9-3      
   000260  5020 8010               ST    2,16(0,8)
```

With TRUNC(BIN)

```
000019  MULTIPLY                                                              
   00023C  4820 8030               LH    2,48(0,8)               PICS9-4      
   000240  5840 8038               L     4,56(0,8)               PICS9-8      
   000244  8E40 0020               SRDA  4,32(0)                              
   000248  5D40 C000               D     4,0(0,12)               SYSLIT AT +0
   00024C  4E50 D120               CVD   5,288(0,13)             TS2=16       
   000250  F154 D110 D123          MVO   272(6,13),291(5,13)     TS2=0        
   000256  4E40 D120               CVD   4,288(0,13)             TS2=16       
   00025A  9110 D115               TM    277(13),X'10'           TS2=5        
   00025E  D204 D115 D123          MVC   277(5,13),291(13)       TS2=5        
   000264  4780 B05C               BC    8,92(0,11)              GN=10(00026C)
   000268  9601 D119               OI    281(13),X'01'           TS2=9        
   00026C                 GN=10    EQU   *                                    
   00026C  4E20 D120               CVD   2,288(0,13)             TS2=16       
   000270  FC82 D111 D125          MP    273(9,13),293(3,13)     TS2=1        
   000276  D202 D128 C008          MVC   296(3,13),8(12)         TS2=24       
   00027C  D204 D12B D115          MVC   299(5,13),277(13)       TS2=27       
   000282  4F20 D128               CVB   2,296(0,13)             TS2=24       
   000286  F144 D12B D110          MVO   299(5,13),272(5,13)     TS2=27       
   00028C  4F50 D128               CVB   5,296(0,13)             TS2=24       
   000290  5C40 C000               M     4,0(0,12)               SYSLIT AT +0
   000294  1E52                    ALR   5,2                                  
   000296  47C0 B08E               BC    12,142(0,11)            GN=11(00029E)
   00029A  5A40 C004               A     4,4(0,12)               SYSLIT AT +4
   00029E                 GN=11    EQU   *                                    
   00029E  1222                    LTR   2,2                                  
   0002A0  47B0 B098               BC    11,152(0,11)            GN=12(0002A8)
   0002A4  5B40 C004               S     4,4(0,12)               SYSLIT AT +4
   0002A8                 GN=12    EQU   *                                    
   0002A8  5050 8040               ST    5,64(0,8)
```

It doesn't take any knowledge of IBM Assembler to work out which of those two pieces of code is going to run more quickly.

The difference in the line-numbers (19 Vs 23) is just down to the fact that TRUNC(BIN) makes the PICture size irrelevant, so where I had three calculations doing the same thing with different size fields, for TRUNC(BIN) the code for each was the same, because the size of each field is the same, a word/fullword of four bytes.

> 3. Native-binary (COMP-5/COMPUTATIONAL-5) does not truncate.

See the code immediately above. It is so massive due to the need to provide truncation. The need to provide decimal truncation is down to the COBOL Standard, it's what must happen in the language.

> 4. TRUNC(OPT) generates optimal code.

The code generated will always be the most efficient for that code-sequence. The same code-sequence will always generate the same code, before optimisation.

However, the optimizer is capable of spotting that a particular undisturbed state is available for a source-field earlier in the program, and replace part or all of the TRUNC(OPT) code with code relying on the previously-available value.

> 5. When using binary fields, always use the maximum PICture for the size of the field

From the same IBM COBOL Cafe discussion referenced above, with these definitions:

```
   01  PIC9-3                       BINARY PIC 999.
   01  PIC9-5                       BINARY PIC 9(5).
   01  THE-RESULT8                  BINARY PIC 9(8).

   01  PIC9-4                       BINARY PIC 9(4).
   01  PIC9-8                       BINARY PIC 9(8).
   01  THE-RESULT                   BINARY PIC 9(8).
```

And these calculations:

```
       MULTIPLY PIC9-4              BY PIC9-8
         GIVING                     THE-RESULT
       MULTIPLY PIC9-3              BY PIC9-5
         GIVING                     THE-RESULT8
```

Here's the generated code for TRUNC(STD):

```
000021  MULTIPLY                                                             
   000248  4830 8018               LH    3,24(0,8)               PIC9-4      
   00024C  5C20 8020               M     2,32(0,8)               PIC9-8      
   000250  5D20 C000               D     2,0(0,12)               SYSLIT AT +0
   000254  5020 8028               ST    2,40(0,8)               THE-RESULT  

000023  MULTIPLY                                                             
   000258  5820 8008               L     2,8(0,8)                PIC9-5      
   00025C  4C20 8000               MH    2,0(0,8)                PIC9-3      
   000260  5020 8010               ST    2,16(0,8)
```

The first block of pseudo-assembler is with the number of digits in the PICture being the maximum that give the same field-size. A BINARY PIC 9(3) occupies a half-word, and 9(4) is the largest that can appear in a half-word. A PIC 9(5) occupies a word/fullword, and, given Myth 7, eight digits is used for that (to be fair to this particular Myth).

The second block is with the number of digits which represent the data accurately, and which don't happen to require truncation when a multiplication is carried out.

Using the "full-size" PICtures *guarantees* that unnecessary truncation will always occur.

The difference in the number of instructions is small, and `LH` is faster than L, so plus to the full-size on that. But `M` is much slower than `L`, and `MH` is slower than `L` but faster than `M`. So plus to the optimal size on that. And the `D` (a divide, which is slow, slow) is not required at all in the second block (because no truncation is required). So bad-boy to the full-size fields on that.

The code for TRUNC(OPT) is also faster for the optimal-size fields, although the difference between the two is not as great (because TRUNC(OPT) in this code-sequence decides it does not need the truncation to base-10 and would not in a million years consider the truncation to field-size).

> 6. When using binary fields, always make them signed.

Again from the same IBM COBOL Cafe discussion, here's same-length signed fields Vs unsigned fields, TRUNC(STD):

```
000019  MULTIPLY                                                             
   000238  4830 8030               LH    3,48(0,8)               PICS9-4     
   00023C  5C20 8038               M     2,56(0,8)               PICS9-8     
   000240  5D20 C000               D     2,0(0,12)               SYSLIT AT +0
   000244  5020 8040               ST    2,64(0,8)               THE-RESULTS

000021  MULTIPLY                                                             
   000248  4830 8018               LH    3,24(0,8)               PIC9-4      
   00024C  5C20 8020               M     2,32(0,8)               PIC9-8      
   000250  5D20 C000               D     2,0(0,12)               SYSLIT AT +0
   000254  5020 8028               ST    2,40(0,8)
```

The code is different from the above when compiled with both TRUNC(OPT) and TRUNC(BIN), but each of the code-sequences in both cases is identical in those options.

The presence or absence of a sign makes no difference to the code generated.

Except in one case. Where Myth 7 comes into play. With a nine-digit binary, using a signed vs unsigned field does generate less code, but that code generated is more code than if using eight digits.

> 7. Since nine decimal digits can fully fit within a word/fullword, there is no problem using nine decimal digits for a COMP/COMP-4/BINARY definition (without TRUNC(BIN)).

From the *IBM Enterprise COBOL Version 4 Release 2 Performance Tuning* paper, pp32-33:

> The following shows the general performance considerations (from most
>   efficient to least efficient) for the number of digits of precision
>   for signed binary data items (using PICTURE S9(n) COMP) using
>   TRUNC(OPT):
>
> n is from 1 to 8
>
> for n from 1 to 4, arithmetic is done in halfword instructions where
>   possible for n from 5 to 8, arithmetic is done in fullword
>   instructions where possible
>
> n is from 10 to 17 arithmetic is done in doubleword format
>
> n is 9
>
> fullword values are converted to doubleword format and then doubleword
>   arithmetic is used (this is SLOWER than any of the above)
>
> n is 18 doubleword values are converted to a higher precision format
>   and then arithmetic is done using this higher precision (this is the
>   SLOWEST of all for binary data items)

There is a similar issue with TRUNC(STD). TRUNC(BIN) already has the built-in slowness for the number of digits 1-9, so is not further affected.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My code is trying to setup the length to a VARCHAR field, according to IBM manual, the definition of it is 49 VAR-LEN PIC S9(4) USAGE BINARY. However, VARCHAR is DB2 support > 10000 bytes. In this case, we cannot follow the field definition as suggested in the DB2 manual?

Comment: @CesarHo A VARCHAR in excess of 9999 bytes is exactly a case for COMP-5 (instead of BINARY). You can't change the size of the field, and you need to express a value more than 9999. COMP-5 will allow you to do that. Can you post a reference to the exact manual/page-number, please?

Comment: @CesarHo just search-engined. DB2 10 for z/OS, Host variables in COBOL, does cover the material if you go through everything, though I really would avoid the suggestion to use TRUNC(BIN). The COMP-5 is in there.

Answer (score 1):

From the publicly available documentation :

```
TRUNC(OPT) is a performance option. When TRUNC(OPT) is in effect, the compiler assumes that data conforms to PICTURE specifications in USAGE BINARY receiving fields in MOVE statements and arithmetic expressions. The results are manipulated in the most optimal way, either truncating to the number of digits in the PICTURE clause, or to the size of the binary field in storage (halfword, fullword, or doubleword). 

Tip: Use the TRUNC(OPT) option only if you are sure that the data being moved into the binary areas will not have a value with larger precision than that defined by the PICTURE clause for the binary item. Otherwise, unpredictable results could occur. This truncation is performed in the most efficient manner possible; therefore, the results are dependent on the particular code sequence generated. It is not possible to predict the truncation without seeing the code sequence generated for a particular statement.
```

Read the "Tip" very carefully and see what it means for your situation.  (Hint : it means it does not make sense to ask the question you did because it literally says that "whatever happens, it was unpredictable" or iow "there is no explanation for what happens").

To make the compiler behaviour predictable, switch to either TRUNC(BIN) or TRUNC(STD).  STD is good for standards compliance but bad for CPU usage, BIN is good for CPU usage but requires you to be a bit careful (because decimal truncation simply will not happen).

Comment: so do you mean that unpredicate behaviour is due to TRUNC(OPT) instead of the LENGTH OF statement and it is possible that case 2 will also be truncated?

Comment: Since the varchar field of DB2 is S9(4) COMP, what's the best practice to move the length there is my record > 10000.

Comment: @CesarHo it is not unpredicted behaviour. The manual tells you that if your data does not conform to PICture (maximum value for PIC 9(4) being 9999) then TRUNC(OPT) must not be used. If you do use it anyway, expect your feet and other random parts of your body to start bleeding.

Comment: @CesarHo if you *need* a two-byte binary to hold more than 9999 (or less than -9999 when signed) then use COMP-5, not COMP/COMP-4/BINARY. If, instead, you can make your field larger, do so - BINARY PIC 9(8) (S if signed, don't be tempted to make it 9(9)).

Comment: DB2 typically has no awareness of how your program is compiled.  Nor should it.  I believe the documented behaviour of DB2 is that it _always_ moves the actual length of what it is working with in those 2 bytes.  Processing that correctly _requires_ that these binary length fields are processed with TRUNC(BIN) - either because that's the option you specify or else because you declare them COMP-5 (which may be entirely exclusive to IBM so should not be done if portability is an issue).

Comment: Bill, binary fields are better always declared signed (unless one knows extremely well what one's doing), and 9(9) fits perfectly well into 4 bytes.  What is the problem that makes this a "temptation" ?

Comment: (I don't know what "about-face" means, but the last paragraph in my answer too is 100% accurate.)

Comment: COMP-5 is unaffected by compiler option TRUNC. Binary fields are not always better signed. About-face means wrong, totally the reverse. For cpu-usage, the order of use of TRUNC is OPT, then STD, then BIN. The 9(9) can cause extra machine-code to be generated, even to the extent that if you want to use values with nine digits it can be more efficient to us 9(10) BINARY. You can wade through this topic, https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=ae9ef6bc-6e4e-43f8-a814-e66bea25fb8c&ps=25, for further discussion and examples of generated code.

Comment: See Enterprise COBOL tuning guides for further description of the 9(9) issue, as well as comparisons of the field-types and compiler options. Note that in V5 there are great improvements in the performance of binaries, see COBPF51.pdf, which deals less with this as it is less of an issue.

Comment: COMP-5 is an IBM Extension to the 1985 Standard. Current standard (2014) has NATIVE-BINARY as a data-type. TRUNC(STD) is "standard truncation", which is decimal truncation. TRUNC(BIN) is to field-size, which  is where the performance issue arises (since the implication that you can truncate requires intermediate results in a larger field).

Comment: Very good answer except for the performance of STD vs BIN in the last paragraph which is, counter-intuitively to many, the wrong way round. If you make the quotes a quote, not code, I think the formatting will be better (no scroll-bar).

Comment: DB2 doesn't need to know how your program is compiled. The thing against TRUNC(BIN) is that it affects *all* BINARY/COMP/COMP-4 fields, not just the ones where you need it. The performance penalty hits the other fields. The performance penalty is irrelevant for the field where you need it, but only because you need it.

Comment: Here you are claiming that TRUNC(BIN) is the option that has the performance hit.  And here's you being quoted from that developerworks thread : "Otherwise use TRUNC(STD) and take the performance hit. ".

Comment: Here is the paragaph: "My advice for V3/V4 is to use the PICture which best defines the data, including size and sign. If a binary contains a non-decimal-limited amount (coming from JAVA, SQL, some CICS system fields, anything similar) then define the individual fields as COMP-5 and never use TRUNC(BIN). Use TRUNC(OPT) if system is guaranteed (and a serious guarantee) to "conform to PICture", which includes ensuring the accumulated fields cannot overflow. Otherwise use TRUNC(STD) and take the performance hit."

Comment: After specifically saying "never use TRUNC(BIN) I then go on to write about TRUNC(OPT) and TRUNC(STD), stating that if data does not conform to PICture you must use TRUNC(STD) (so not TRUNC(OPT)) and take the performance hit of that. You can't benefit from the performance of TRUNC(OPT) without data conforming to PICture (as in your original quote from the manual). TRUNC(BIN) has a further performance hit over TRUNC(STD). Also, unless you use @BillWoodger (after typing the @ you'll see a list of those you can @) I don't see your comments unless I come looking.